# Is it necessary to free the memory of strings in C++ received from C#?

Tags: c#, c++, memory-leaks, interop, marshalling

I have the following exposed DLL functions in C++.

```cpp
// center_of_rotation_api.h
// CENTER_OF_ROTATION_API is a macro like __cdecl(dllexport) on Windows
CENTER_OF_ROTATION_API void SerializeMesh(Mesh * mesh, const char * path);
CENTER_OF_ROTATION_API const char * SerializationError(Mesh * mesh);
```

From C#, I use the following.

```cs
// dll is the name of the compiled dll
    [DllImport(dll)]
    public static extern void SerializeMesh(IntPtr mesh, string path);
    [DllImport(dll)]
    public static extern IntPtr SerializationError(IntPtr mesh);
```

The `IntPtr` returned by `SerializationError` is allocated using `new` in C++. So I have another DLL exported function that frees the pointer when called by C#.

My question is, do I need to free the memory of the `const char * path` in the argument of `SerializeMesh` in C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the C# marshaler will take care of this for you. The `char*` will be valid during the lifetime of the PInvoke call. If your C++ code expects to own the `char*`, you should make a copy in `SerializeMesh`.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/marshaling-strings) is a primer on string marshaling. If you really need to use a `const char*`, you might need to set the [MarshalAsAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute?view=net-5.0) to `UnmanagedType.LPStr`. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshaling-for-strings?redirectedfrom=MSDN) for more information on string marshaling behavior.

[Here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/138614/Advanced-Topics-in-PInvoke-String-Marshaling) is another useful reference if you want to dig even deeper.